# What is the word-grammar transcription thing called?

Tags: conlang-creation, tools, glossing

What is the thing used under a sentence in a conlang that looks sort of like this: NOM-he.F-PAST said.F-PAST called?
I know I probably used it completely wrong in that example, but what is this called, and how does it work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

The thing is called a [gloss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlinear_gloss). There is a widely used standard for such glosses, the [Leipzig glossing rules](https://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/resources/glossing-rules.php).